# How to Generate PDF using Active Reports

Tags: c#, pdf, activereports

I'm generating PDF template using Active Report 
.

Below is code I write but when I run code PDF is generated but not open it shows may be PDF is not created correctly

```
    public partial class CheckListReport : GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReport
    {
        string fileNameNew = @"D:\Omkar1\ActiveReportCheckList.pdf";
        public void ReportsDate()
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileNameNew, FileMode.Create))
            {
                string date = DateTime.Today.ToString();
                string versionNo = "1.0.77";

                richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular);
                richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
                richTextBox1.ReplaceField("Report Generated On", date);
                richTextBox1.ReplaceField("Version Number", versionNo);
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there any other way to Generate PDF because I want to see template format

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is another way you can generate a PDF.  Since you are using section reports, you will have to use **Export Filters**.
Please refer to the sample code and PDF Export Filter sample below:

```
// Export the report in PDF format.
GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Export.Pdf.Section.PdfExport PdfExport1 = new GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Export.Pdf.Section.PdfExport();
PdfExport1.Export(MyDocument, Application.StartupPath + "\\PDFExpt.pdf");
```

https://www.grapecity.com/activereports/docs/v14/online/pdf-export.html

In addition, you can refer to another sample below that utilizes the PDF Export Filter:
https://github.com/activereports/Samples14/tree/master/API/Section/Export

Check out our documentation for more information about exporting:
https://www.grapecity.com/activereports/docs/v14/online/exporting.html

Sincerely,

GrapeCity Support Team

https://www.grapecity.com/support/contact